# Circular Progress keeps on rotating

Tags: flutter

I tried to implement the CircularProgressBar for flutter, but somehow, it keeps on spinning, not going off after loading data.

calling  data from NetworkFile

```
 final getCategory = NetworkFile().getCategories(elem);
  bool isLoading = true;
  List posts = [];

  void getPostsList() async {
    var res = await getCategory;

    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        posts = res;

      });
    }
  }
```

Returning the container

```
return isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(), }
         ), 
     );
```

Comment: after you get data, you should change isLoading state to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  setState(() {
        posts = res;
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Use `FutureBuilder` instead.

Comment: neeed a bit time to change ListView to FutureBuilder. But will definitely go with it